# Vim: command of a plugin are not recognized with minimal_vimrc

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I am debugging a plugin and start vim with `vim --servername VIM -u minimal.vim minimal.tex`. The plugin is loaded automatically and the plugin's name is in the output of `:scriptnames`, `:h local-additions` and `:set runtimepath?` commands, but no command defined by the plugin works: `E492: Not an editor command:`. Issuing a `:packadd <packagename>` does not change the situation.

What am I doing wrong? What do I need to do to load that plugin? How to use a plugin with as pure vim config as possible?

The minimal vimrc:

```
set nocompatible
let &runtimepath  = '~/.vim/bundle/vimtex,' . &runtimepath
let &runtimepath .= ',~/.vim/bundle/vimtex/after'
filetype plugin indent on
syntax enable
```

---

**Update**: When I looked a little deeper into it next day, I realized that other plugins are working. Since it reduces the issue from a general vim debug question to a plugin specific one, I would contact the creator of the plugin. I will post the solution when I will have one. (The plugin in question is vimtex)

Comment: Your question is quite vague since you barely show the things that aren't working and you only mention *which* plugin isn't working in the vimrc snippet... Show the output of scriptnames to indicate *which* script is being loaded. Looks like you're editing a `*.tex` file, but what does `:set ft?` say about the file type? Which command are you running that fails with E492? Can you also paste your `:set runtimepath?` output? All of these would be crucial to answer your question...

Comment: `What am I doing wrong?` You forgot `packpath`

Comment: Check `vim --version`: is `+packages` there?

Comment: Matt and phd: If the plugin is really at `~/.vim/bundle/vimtex` then packages are most definitely not in use. No wonder *"Issuing a :packadd <packagename> does not change the situation."* But this question needs a lot more details to elicit an useful answer, see my comment above.

Comment: I’m not sure those tildes `~` get expanded—you should use the full path.